# How to send HTTP Auth Credentials with a WCF Service Reference

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I'm attempting to consume a HTTP Basic Auth Secured PHP WebService using VB.NET. I've so far managed to get 100% perfect integration by adding it as a Web Reference and doing the following:

```
Dim Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
Dim CredentialCache = New System.Net.CredentialCache()
CredentialCache.Add(New Uri(MyWebService.Url), "Basic", Credentials)
MyWebService.Credentials = CredentialCache
MyWebService.PreAuthenticate = True
```

I can also successfully add the webservice as a 'Service Reference' and this also works fine, as long as i turn off all HTTP authentication on the SOAP server.

My problem is that I can't find any documented means of sending basic HTTP Auth Credentials when using Service References as opposed to 'Web References'

Am I right in my understanding that 'Web References' are a legacy method of Web Service consumption?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx) shows a client implementation for WCF using Basic Authentication.